# Combine same String in dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

We have below dataframe

```
d1 = {'data': ['python','Python','PYTHON','conda', 'COnda', 'CONDA', ],
        'Value': [50,25,30,25,40,25]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns = ['data', 'Value']) 

data    Value
0   python  50
1   Python  25
2   PYTHON  30
3   conda   25
4   COnda   40
5   CONDA   25
```

And we need to combine same strings values in one rows using python and expected output like

```
    data    Value
0   Python  105
1   Conda   90
```

Comment: `groupby` is what you want. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html The first example is kind same with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
>>> df['data'] = df.data.str.capitalize()
>>> df.groupby('data', sort=False).sum().reset_index()

     data  Value
0  Python    105
1   Conda     90
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using title() function:

```
df['data'] = [val.title() for val in df['data']]

df1 = df.groupby('data', sort=False).sum().reset_index()

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     data  Value
0  Python    105
1   Conda     90
```